# Plot not showing when using python multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing, and it works good except when I need to plot something. The structure of the code is something like

```
def Code(x,y):
     do_something
     plt.plot(X_values,Y_values)
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.starmap(Code, Z)#Z is a tuple containing (0.015,0.02)
    #Code(0.015,0.02)
```

When I use the commented part to call the *Code* function it works fine, however when I use Pool is not showing the plot, and additionally I can't see anything that I print inside the *Code* function.
What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Any comment is appreciated. Thanks

**PS:**  The plot is just to verify some results, it is not very complicated. Additionally I believe pool is working properly because I am extracting the data into a csv file and everything seems to work, the only problem is when I try to plot something inside *Code*.

Comment: Is your environment set up to use a non-GUI backend? Normally, when you call something like `plt.plot()`, this brings up a window which _blocks_ the program until it is closed, usually by clicking the "x" in the upper left corner. This would block those background processes until the figure is closed, which you have no way of doing here.

Answer (score 0):

The subprocesses in your pool probably don't have access to the display to launch the plot window. You could try to debug that, but do you really want to end up with a separate plot window for each result?

Usually, when I use multiprocessing, I distribute all the data to the subprocesses in the pool, collect the results in the main process, and then display a summary by combining all the results together. In this case, I would make `Code()` return the results of the calculation, and do the plotting in the main process.

Also, consider switching to [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor). It doesn't have as many features as `Pool`, but it has some bug fixes that avoid a frozen pool when a child process gets killed.